# Ionic application : Android --livereload shows cordova not available error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic app...

I tried to run the application using **ionic serve** which shows:

> Runtime error: Uncaught(in promise):cordova_not_available

Then I have added browser platform and run using **ionic cordova run browser**
Then I got no error in browser but no action too, in console I found **cant open sqlite database**.

Then I added Android platform and run using **ionic cordova run android**
Everything works fine...

I thought to reload the application without running every time so I run using **ionic cordova run android --livereload**
then I got the same first error:

> Runtime error: Uncaught(in promise):cordova_not_available

So I couldn't figure out what mistake I have exactly done with cordova. Why is it showing a different error each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following commands in CLI
if you want to emulate in Android with console logs and server logs use this:

```
$ ionic emulate android --livereload --consolelogs --serverlogs
```

to just run on android use this:

```
$ ionic run android -l -c -s
```

First go through this
If you want the plugin to work for the browser you should add platform browser and run it:

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

and run it:

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

instead of `ionic serve`
If all these above not works try re-installing cordova by the following command:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

and check the installed version using below command:

```
cordova --version
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,
[12:42:08]  console.warn: Native: tried accessing the SQLite plugin but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include
            cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
[12:42:08]  console.log: cordova_not_available

Am getting this in console...